# FileInfo.CopyTo returns ArgumentException:

Tags: c#, file, copy

I'm importing and parsing some JSON and just to make sure it doesn't screw up or corrupt my existing data, I'm parsing everything to a temp directory and then trying to copy it over when I'm done. The issue is that I'm getting a confusing ArgumentException at runtime.

Here's the code:

```
DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(tempPath);
    FileInfo[] files = dir.GetFiles();
    for(int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
    {
        files[i].CopyTo(fPathBase,true); //Watching this in the debugger I see all the files.
    }
```

And the exception I'm getting is ArgumentException:

> C:\Users\Me\AppData\LocalLow\ACGF\ac\qs\testTopic\ is a directory

Which. Yes. Yes, it is. What is it trying to tell me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**CopyTo** copies the content of one file from another file. However, you are specifying the directory instead of the file name. That is the cause of your exception. Refer [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5axsfwbc(v=vs.110).aspx) for more details

Comment: Your MSDN link isn't working correctly. It is producing some invalid link.

Comment: Updated @RBT! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Classic missing the point! The first parameter of FileInfo.CopyTo is the FILENAME, not the path. So it should be

```
files[i].CopyTo(fPathBase + fileName + extension,true);
```